# Final numbers of $2003^{2003}$ and $2003^{2003^{2003}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What are the three final numbers of $2003^{2003}$ and $2003^{2003^{2003}}$?

Do I use the Chinese Remainder Theorem here, and if so, how?

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem won't be very useful to be honest. Just view it mod $1000$. Some work will be needed for the second part probably.

Comment: You need to use modular arithmetic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) for the module $1000$

Comment: The middle digits of $2003^{2003}$ are $14$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To find the last three digits means to find the residue class $\pmod{1000}$.

Since $\varphi(1000)=400$, by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_theorem) we have:
$$ 2003^{2003}\equiv 3^{3}\equiv 27\pmod{1000},$$
so the last three digits of $2003^{2003}$ are $\color{red}{027}$.

To do the same with $2003^{2003^{2003}}$, we have to understand what $2003^{2003}\pmod{400}$ is. Since:
$$ 2003^{2003}\equiv 3^{83}\equiv 27\pmod{400}, $$
because $3^{83}\equiv 3^3\equiv 2\pmod{25}$ and $3^{83}\equiv 11\pmod{16}$, we have:
$$ 2003^{2003^{2003}}\equiv 3^{27}\equiv 987\pmod{1000}$$
and the last three digits of $2003^{2003^{2003}}$ are $\color{red}{987}$.

Comment: +1 What an amazing theorem! I always wondered how those answers were made.

Answer (score 2):

[Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) guarantees that, if $\gcd(a,1000)=1$ then
$$a^{400}\equiv 1\pmod {1000}$$
that is, the three last digits of $a^{400}$ will be $001$.

Then, since $2003\equiv 3\pmod {1000}$ and $2003\equiv 3\pmod{400}$, then
$$2003^{2003}\equiv 3^3\equiv 27\pmod {1000}$$
that is, the three last digits of $2003^{2003}$ are $027$.

Can you try the second one?

Comment: $3$ and $3^4=81$ share no digits ........

Comment: $3$ and $3^5=243$ share only the last digit (singular) not the last digits (the OP asks for the last three)

Comment: Fixed again. I didn't realize taht the OP said 'three digits'.

Answer (score 1):

$\varphi(1000)=\left(2^3-2^2\right)\left(5^3-5^2\right)=400$, so by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem) (since $(3,1000)=1$):

$$2003^{2003}\equiv 3^{2003\pmod{\! 400}}\equiv 3^3\equiv 27\pmod{\! 1000}$$

You can shorten Jack's answer using [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) (since $(3,400)=1$):

$$\lambda(400)=\lambda(2^4\cdot 5^2)=\text{lcm}\left(\lambda\left(2^4\right),\lambda(5^2)\right)=\text{lcm}\left(4,20\right)=20$$

$$2003^{2003^{2003}}\equiv 3^{3^{2003\pmod{\! 20}}\pmod{\! 400}}\equiv 3^{3^{3}}\equiv 987\pmod{\! 1000}$$

Answer (score 0):

As $\displaystyle2003\equiv3\pmod{1000}$

$$2003^{2003^{2003}}\equiv3^{2003^{2003}}\pmod{1000}$$

Now  Carmichael function $\lambda(1000)=\cdots=100$

$$\implies3^{2003^{2003}}\equiv3^{2003^{2003}\pmod{100}}\pmod{1000}$$

As $\displaystyle2003\equiv3\pmod{100},2003^{2003}\equiv3^{2003}\pmod{100}$

Now $\displaystyle3^{2003}=\cdots=3(-1+10)^{1001}\equiv3\{(-1)^{1001}+\binom{1001}1(-1)^{1000}10^1\}\pmod{100}$

$\displaystyle\equiv3[-1+1001\cdot10]\equiv3\cdot9\equiv27$

$\displaystyle\implies3^{2003^{2003}}\equiv3^{27}\pmod{1000}$

Again, $\displaystyle3^{27}=3\cdot3^{26}=3(-1+10)^{13}$

and $\displaystyle(-1+10)^{13}\equiv(-1)^{13}+\binom{13}1(-1)^{12}10^1-\binom{13}2(-1)^{11}10^2\pmod{1000}$

$\displaystyle\equiv-1+13\cdot10-\dfrac{13\cdot12}2\cdot100\equiv-671\equiv329$

Can you take it home from here?